# How to Set System Properties for Tomcat 6.X

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7

Experts
I want to Set Tomcat 6.0 System Properties , but i don't have any *.bat files in my tomcat folder , so is there any other solution for my problem ??

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: what properties do you want to set? How are you starting Tomcat - are you on windows or unix?

Comment: I use win XP. I want to Set org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK to true.

Comment: Are you starting with `tomcat.exe` ?

Comment: Yes, I am starting with tomcat.exe.

Answer (score 2):

You must be using windows isnatller version of tomcat. 
Open tomcat manager by double clicking its icon in task bar.
goto java tab, and add your properites e.g. myProp=myVal will be:
-DmyProp=myVal
specify each property in a separate line.